# destroy Ember Controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm calling `destroy()` on a controller when I leave a certain view (not the viewcontroller but an additional controller that I use).
If I then go back in that same view, the controller is still there, it has the properties:

```
_didCallDestroy: true
isDestroyed: true
isDestroying: true
```

all set as expected, but my view is still binding to them. Is it not destroying because it's content still holds data? What could be causing this?

Comment: Why do you want to call destroy manually? There are only few cases, when you want to do it yourself. This is a method, which is most often exclusively called by the EmberJS framework.

Comment: @mavilein I created them myself manually, in those cases you need to destory them manually also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional arraycontrollers mentioned above are placed in an array. The solution was to not only destroy the controllers but also reset the array to []:

```
this.get('dataSets').forEach(function (ds) {
  ds.destroy();
});
this.set('dataSets', []);
```